# Using Python to traverse a parent-child data set

Tags: python, recursion, csv

I have a dataset of two columns in a csv file. Th purpose of this dataset is to provide a linking between two different id's if they belong to the same person. e.g (2,3,5 belong to 1)
e.g

```
 1. COLA COLB 1 2 ; 1 3 ; 1 5 ; 2 6 ; 3 7 ; 9 10
```

In the above example 1 is linked to 2,3,5 and 2 is the linked to 6 and 3 is linked to 7.
What I am trying to achieve is to identify all records which are linked to 1 directly (2,3,5) or indirectly (6,7) and be able to say that these id's in column B belong to same person in column A and then either dedupe or add a new column to the output file which will have 1 populated for all rows that link to 1

Example of expected output

```
 - colA  colB GroupField 1 2 1; 1 3 1;  1 5 1 ;
2 6 1 ;3 7 1; 9 10 9; 10 11 9
```

How to approach this problem?

So far I have been able to read the file in and create a dictionary. I have researched on using Python set operation but am unable to use them with a dictionary.

I have researched ways to convert a dictionary to a set and then use set operators to de-dupe between sets but can't find anything online for it and not sure if that's even the right way to approach this problem.

Comment: What have you done so far?  Neither P.SE (nor SO) is a code writing service.

Comment: Hi Michael,So far I have been able to read the file in and create a dictionary. I have researched on using Python set operation but am unable to use them with a dictionary. I have researched ways to convert a dictionary to a set and then use set operators to de-dupe between sets but can't find anything online for it and not sure if that's even the right way to approach this problem. I am not looking for actual code, just an idea of how to approach this so that I can spend my time researching the suggested methods and try implementing the same.

Comment: How many steps are allowed to consider that two ID's are connected "indirectly"? Also, does the `GroupField` mean "all these records are connected and I am assigning to this group the ID of the first record found"?

Comment: Also, where does the `10 11 9` output come from? There is no `11` in the input

Comment: Hi logc --- There isn't a fixed number of steps to consider if two id's are connected indirectly as this could vary from id to id. The group ID field is sort of like a group by field. For values in colB which are linked directly or indirectly, I would like to insert the top level parent present in colA. Since these id's are numbers, I would sort the dataset by colA and then colB to be able to pick the top level id. I added 11 and 9 to the output to indicate that 9 is a separate parent and has a seperate linking from ID 1

Answer (score 0):

Your input is a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29), and there are [many Python libraries](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGraphApi) to help you analyze one. [NetworkX](http://networkx.github.io) is one of them.

You are looking for [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) in the graph, and there are [a number of functions in NetworkX](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms.component.html?highlight=component) to find them.

Some code lines to get you started:

```
import networkx as nx

file_contents = "1 2 ; 1 3 ; 1 5 ; 2 6 ; 3 7 ; 9 10"
lines = [item.strip() for item in file.split(";")]
G = nx.parse_edgelist(lines, nodetype = int)
components = nx.connected_components(G)
# components now holds:
# [[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], [9, 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Logc thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to solve this problem using a little bit of networkx and using Tarjan's algorithm on strongly connected components. Below is  my code :-

```
import networkx as nx
def strongly_connected_components(graph):
""" Find the strongly connected components in a graph using
    Tarjan's algorithm.

    graph should be a dictionary mapping node names to
    lists of successor nodes.
    """

    result = [ ]
    stack = [ ]
    low = { }

def visit(node):
    if node in low: return

num = len(low)
    low[node] = num
    stack_pos = len(stack)
    stack.append(node)

    for successor in graph[node]:
        visit(successor)
        low[node] = min(low[node], low[successor])

    if num == low[node]:
    component = tuple(stack[stack_pos:])
        del stack[stack_pos:]
        result.append(component)
    for item in component:
        low[item] = len(graph)

for node in graph:
    visit(node)

    return result


def topological_sort(graph):
     count = { }
     for node in graph:
        count[node] = 0
     for node in graph:
         for successor in graph[node]:
              count[successor] += 1

     ready = [ node for node in graph if count[node] == 0 ]

    result = [ ]
    while ready:
       node = ready.pop(-1)
       result.append(node)

       for successor in graph[node]:
           count[successor] -= 1
           if count[successor] == 0:
              ready.append(successor)

return result

def robust_topological_sort(graph):
""" First identify strongly connected components,
    then perform a topological sort on these components. """

components = strongly_connected_components(graph)

node_component = { }
for component in components:
    for node in component:
        node_component[node] = component

component_graph = { }
for component in components:
    component_graph[component] = [ ]

for node in graph:
    node_c = node_component[node]
    for successor in graph[node]:
        successor_c = node_component[successor]
        if node_c != successor_c:
            component_graph[node_c].append(successor_c) 

return topological_sort(component_graph)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  print robust_topological_sort({
    0 : [1],
    1 : [2],
    2 : [1,3],
    3 : [3],
})

graph = nx.read_edgelist('input_filename',
create_using=None,delimiter=',',nodetype=None,edgetype=None)
results = strongly_connected_components(graph)
f=open('output_filename','w')
for item in results:
  f.write(','.join(map(str,item)))
  f.write('\n')
f.close()
```